# UICollectionView contentSize.width is wrong

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am running into a very strange situation. I have a UICollectionView in a storyboard and I'm using the standard horizontal flow layout. I have the size of the cell set to 80x80.

However, when I run the app the cells are not stacked horizontally. When I examine `collectionView.frame.width`, it has the right width (which is the width of the screen). But `collectionView.contentSize.width` is 80!!

Any idea how I can get the collectionView to use the whole width?

Comment: where you check that width value ?

Answer (score 0):

When using horizontal flow layout the width of the content view apparently grows with the number of columns filled up with cells.

The content of a collection view that has one column will be less in width than the same collection view with two columns ...

[image: One column] [image: Two columns]

When a minimum content view width is required, property `sectionInset` left and right values could be set accordingly.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
   ... 
   myLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 100, bottom: 0, right: 600)
}
```